# Which scoring function does Sklearn Random Forest use

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the GridSearchCV [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) you can parse in a `score` function. If None is parsed, it will use the default score function (for the function you are grid-searching over).

The question is for, say, a Random Forest - what is the scoring function? For other algorithms, how do I determine that? I cannot find anything about scoring in the Random Forest [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scoring is `the mean accuracy`:

> ```
> score(self, X, y[, sample_weight])    Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
> ```

Ref: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score

---

The different scoring options can be found here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: Argh, how did I miss that?

Comment: Yeah, but I had to wait 10 minutes before I could do it. Thanks :)

Comment: just in case someone needs the answer for RandomForestRegressor, then the answer is R2 - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html